# what is the maximum lenght of sessions ASP.net 4.0 session ID - store as varchar or char or nvarchar?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, asp.net-4.0, sessionid

I checked my own server session Ids and they are all 24 characters

I am storing each logged in person session Id at my sql server

So my question is

having a column

`char(24)` is enough for storing SessionIds of visitors ?

ASP.net 4.0

```
Session kept as : State Server tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? ASP.NET supports persisting sessions in db automatically if configured as such.

Comment: I'm a little confused - are you using ASP.NET's built-in SQL Server session store or are you trying to roll your own? See http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3595766/Storing-Session-State-in-a-SQL-Server-Database.htm for using ASP.NET's built-in SQL Server session store.

Comment: As others commented - if you need to do this, you are doing something wrong. When setting the state server you should be using the asp.net utilities provided - they will create the state database with the fields needed. You shouldn't be messing with that.

Comment: i am not doing anything to the generated session ids. just preventing double login from different browsers via checking each loggin sessions by just storing session Ids at database :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting aside whether you should be doing this or not, the SessionIDManager enforces an 80-character limit on session IDs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.sessionidmaxlength(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: ye but i am asking default. i am not using any custom session id manager.

Comment: Yes, by default the session ID is a 24-character alphanumeric string.  See the remarks section here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager(v=vs.100).aspx